# I get the following error from this syntax

Tags: c#, sql

Im using the following SQL Syntax

```
command . CommandText="INSERT INTO Group(GroupName, Groupcomment, GroupIconPath) values (@name, @comment ,@path)";
```

then VS is giving me the error INVALID SYNTAX NEAR GROUP

I checked a few times i dont find any errors hmm

Answer (score 2):

Use brackets around the table name. This tells SQL Server that you don't mean the reserved keyword.

```
command.CommandText="INSERT INTO [Group](GroupName, Groupcomment, GroupIconPath) values (@name, @comment ,@path)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Group is a reserved keyword, you can wrap it in square brackets to make this work:

```
command.CommandText="INSERT INTO [Group](GroupName, Groupcomment, GroupIconPath) values .."
```

Answer (score 0):

Group is a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) in SQL Server. Might have to rename your table.

Comment: As mentioned, you can escape the reserved keyword by using brackets around the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Try tris..

```
command . CommandText="INSERT INTO `Group`(GroupName, Groupcomment, GroupIconPath) values (@name, @comment ,@path)";
```

Answer (score 0):

`group` is a keyword in SQL.

Put [] around it like this `[group]`